# ember.js: catching url enter event

Tags: ember.js

In ember.js I need to trigger a modal box create when I enter inside an URL, and to trigger its destruction when i leave it.

Do you know what events i can observe?

Will they be triggered in the controller or in the route?

And, finally, where can i find the documentation for this? I couldn't find any in ember.js site

I tried the `enter` and `leave` event, but they are triggered only once, and in the wrong moment

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `activate` and `deactivate` hooks on the `Ember.Route`.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html